# How do launch an executable from a custom strip and tile in Windows Media Center start menu?

Tags: windows, windows-media-center

I have added a custom strip and tile to Windows Media Center. However when I select the tile then my chosen application (`notepad.exe`) doesn't launch and I get the following error:

> The [name] program has stopped responding and you will be
>   returned to Windows Media Center.

What do I need to change in my XML so that  `notepad.exe` is launched rather than displaying this error message?

---

### Further details

Using the examples provided [at this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/08/04/adding-strips-and-tiles-to-the-windows-media-center-start-menu-in-windows-vista/) and [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189042.aspx) at the Windows Dev Center, I've created the following XML file (called `dummy.xml`):

```
<application title="appTitle" id="{81E3517C-A5F3-4afa-9E37-81BF9A6A99FE}">
    <entrypoint id="{760A3CF3-6675-444b-AA31-B2A3F94AD9A3}"
        addin="Microsoft.MediaCenter.Hosting.WebAddIn,Microsoft.MediaCenter"
        title="entrypointTitle"
        description="Description"
        run="notepad.exe">
        <category category="MyCompany\MyApplication1"/>
    </entrypoint>  
</application>
```

and the following registry file (called `dummy.reg`):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Media Center\Start Menu\Applications\{81E3517C-A5F3-4afa-9E37-81BF9A6A99FE}]
"Title"="appTitle"
"Category"="MyCompany\\MyApplication1"
"OnStartMenu"="True"
"TimeStamp"=dword:0c7e59de
```

I then install them using the following commands:

```
%windir%\ehome\registermceapp.exe dummy.xml
regedit.exe /s dummy.reg
```

When I run Windows Media Center, then I can see the strip and tile - but when I select the tile then I get an error message:

[image: The [tile name] program has stopped responding and you will be returned to Windows Media Center.]

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms813936.aspx), the `entrypoint` element has the attribute `run` which is:

> A string that specifies the full or relative path to an executable file on the local computer.

What do I need to do differently with the XML file and registry key to get `notepad.exe` to run, rather than an error message being shown?

Comment: Your `dummy.reg` category does not match your `dummy.xml` category. Maybe fix and try again? Your `.reg` has 2 slashes. Maybe it was just a typo when creating the question though.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/01/07/mailbag-how-to-launch-an-exe-from-within-windows-media-center/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be twofold:

1. Not reading the documentation correctly
2. `RegisterMceApp.exe` reporting "Success" even when the XML is incorrect.

On [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms813936.aspx) which documents the `entrypoint` element, it quite clearly states:

```
<entrypoint
    id="entry point GUID"

    <!-- This element can have only one of the following attributes:
    addin="AssemblyInfo"
    url="URL of entry-point page"
    run="path of EXE file"
    -->
```

My XML file used both `addin` and `run` which is why it didn't work.

The corrected version below (combined with the original registry file) will cause `notepad.exe` to launch when the tile is selected from within Windows Media Center:

```
<application title="appTitle" id="{81E3517C-A5F3-4afa-9E37-81BF9A6A99FE}">
    <entrypoint id="{760A3CF3-6675-444b-AA31-B2A3F94AD9A3}"
        run="notepad.exe"
        title="entrypointTitle"
        description="Description">
        <category category="MyCompany\MyApplication1"/>
    </entrypoint>  
 </application>
```